# How can I increase my eating speed?

Tags: food, personal-care, comfort, efficiency

My eating speed is not as fast as normal people. In parties and other events I can't eat according to my need because of speed issue. In friends circle when we eat something they make fun of my eating speed.It become a serious issue for me. 
How can I improve my eating speed?

Comment: What is the exact nature of the speed being slower?  Is it comfort, heartburn, fear, embarassment, physical impairment, or something else?  That answer will change the responses you get to be more helpful, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your eating strategy and don't be embarassed.

1. Eating slowly is actually a very good and healthy thing. Your friends are the ones in the wrong way, don't feel the need to change because of bad social ideology.
2. Eat what you can, and save the rest for later.
3. If you feel embarassed, eat what you can and abandon the rest. Its not unusual to not finish your food where i come from. Eat a small amount from each dish. You will seem really posh and people will think you have really high taste to not be desperate and rush to finish food.

Jatt